# Как отправить 5 ТБ данных на сервер

Tags: сервер, hdd, ssd

Возникла задача отправлять большое количество информации на сервер.
Что имеем, так это интернет 1 Гбит и ПК.

И сам диск с информацией, как я понял HDD диск, какой бы он не был, максимум до 250 Мбит/с, а информацию мне нужно передать в течении 12 часов.

Правильно я понимаю, что для этого мне нужно минимум использовать SSD? Или как это всё сделать?
Возможно ли такое сделать через NAS к примеру, чтобы не использовать ПК?

Comment: `(((5242880 / 31.25) * 60) * 60) ≈ 603,979,776 ч` это нереально при такой скорости диска. Разве только при сжатии.

Comment: Получается чтобы хоть как то приблизиться к данной отметке, то использовать SSD? А в лучшем случае нужен SSD M2?

Comment: Не выйдет за такое время даже при скорости интернета в 1GBps... Так что здесь даже диск не спасет.

Comment: А можно узнать почему? По расчету к примеру 5 ТБ данных можно передать примерно за 12-13 часов. Или я неправильно считаю?

Comment: Вы знаете чем отличается `GBps` от `GB/s`? Так вот, `GBps` это не 1 Гигабайт в секунду, а 1 Гигабит в секунду, т.е. `1024/8`. Вот и пересчитайте.

Comment: Иногда может оказаться быстрей и выгодней перевезти накопитель физически. В некоторых странах даже есть компании, которые предлагают такие услуги (грузовики гоняют).

Comment: Я сейчас понял, что просто неправильно все считал. Жесткий диск передача до 250 МБ в секунду, и скорость получается до 125 МБ в секунду. Тогда все нормально?

Answer (score 1):

Копирование данных на ссд не даст меньшее время, потому как вы потратите время на их копирование.

1 Гбит/с интернет это 120 мегабайт в секунду - в лучшем случае 12 часов на передачу.

Я уменьшаю это время используя сжатие - очень хорошо помогает если это база данных - не помогает если это видео.

```
tar -c /files | gzip -9 | netcat serverip  5555
```

На другой стороне

```
netcat -l 5555 | gunzip | tar -e -C /
```

Но таким способом не обеспечить восстановление при обрыве соединения.

Для более надежной передачи используйте rsync, filezilla или torrent.

Comment: Да, остается вариант только через torrent. Я буду отправлять, а вторая сторона в этот момент получать. Так как файл у меня один в 5 ТБ, уже зашифрованный, и нужна будет догрузка если что то где то перестанет работать.